# VBS - How to pause a script until a key is pressed?

Tags: vbscript, console, key, wait, sleep

How to pause the script until a key is pressed in VBScript?
I need something that would pause the flow of the program and wait until 'left_arrow' key is pressed.

Comment: `MsgBox` Function, see [VBScript Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x(v=vs.84).aspx)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't have a lot of choices. If you have a console script, and I'm assuming you do, you can read input from the user but it only registers when you press [ENTER]. So you could pause until the enter key is pressed. For example:

```
WScript.Echo "Press [ENTER] to continue..."

' Read dummy input. This call will not return until [ENTER] is pressed.
WScript.StdIn.ReadLine

WScript.Echo "Done."
```

There's also the old `pause` command from DOS days. However, shelling a new console window to run `pause` would cause a second window to appear. You'd need to press a key in *that* window to return to your script. Probably not what you want.

But apart from third-parties, VBScript has no methods to read keypresses at run-time.